# Planting shrubs around town tree AC:NL

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

Online, I have seen people with shrubs around their town tree. My tree is developed enough that I can see the town history. I also have the golden shovel, but I cannot figure out how to plant shrubs around my town tree. please help me out.

Comment: http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Bush

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I play AC:NL. I don't think you can plant shrubs arounds your town tree unless you use something like homebrew and hack the game, where you can move and place items almost anywhere you want to.